# Looping through a JavaScript array and then taking all the element and making them one string

Tags: javascript

new to JS and I'm trying to append all the elements of an array to one string or element. I have tried a few different things but to no luck.

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.foodlist.length; i++) {
   const foodlist_obj = data.foodlist.item[i];
   console.log(foodlist_obj)
}
```

This returns a list like so:

Apple

Banana

Orange

Grapes

etc

But I would love to get the list to be like "Apple, Banana, Orange, Grapes, etc".
I have tried to use append and a few other options but cant seem to figure it out any help is appreciated

Comment: Not sure I follow -- can you clarify what you need, please? Where'd Banana go? Normally if you want the array as one string, you use `.join(yourDelimiter)`, e.g. `const joined = data.foodlist.join(" ")` or `.join(", ")`. `append` isn't a JS function I'm aware of, so it's good to show your actual attempts.

Comment: So the output is like the above, but I want the add or join them to one element or string is like: "Apple, Banana, Orange, Grapes, etc"

Comment: Sounds good, thanks. Did you try the code I gave you? How'd it work for you? Also, do you literally want the word "etc" on the end or ...?

Comment: What is `data.foodlist`? An array? If so, what does `data.footlist.item[i]` do?

Comment: So its from a api call so data is how Im storing it the DB, so data.foodlist.item[i] is all the items in the array element, so it can be any number of items

Comment: @CardsGuy Can you show a snippet of this data? I realized my code suggestions probably don't match your structure -- I missed the `.item` prop. That's a rather unusual way to iterate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This returns a list like so:

It does not return a list. `const foodlist_obj` is a local variable within the  for loop and as such it's being reset at every iteration. What is logged is a single string variable 5 times.

You need to declare the variable outside the loop as an array, then append to it.

```
const foodlist_obj = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.foodlist.length; i++) {
   foodlist_obj[foodlist_obj.length] = data.foodlist.item[i];
}
console.log(foodlist_obj)
```

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense now. I thought it was returning a list, not as variables for each item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to concatenate the items:

```js
const data = {foodlist:['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Grapes']}
const joined = data.foodlist.join(", ");
console.log(joined);
```

Answer (score 0):

- if you want to get them as string you can use `toString()` method

```
const foodlist_obj = data.foodlist.toString()
```

- also you can use `join()` to replace comma separate with any other thing like new line

```
const foodlist_obj = data.foodlist.join("\n")
```

- if you wants to get them as text with a special syntax you can create a variable called `text` and set it's type to string then add the array elements when loop

```
var text = "";
for (let i = 0; i < data.foodlist.length; i++) {
   text += data.foodlist[i] + " item number("+i+")\n";
}
console.log(text)
```

- if you get error that's will be of you because in your code you looping through `data.foodlist`  but when you called the array you called him as `data.foodlist.item[i]` how do you called `item` property when you looping through `data.foodlist` you should call it like that `data.foodlist[i]` so check your array good first before loop
- also you testing the `foodlist_obj` when you still loop and that's shouldn't give you something except one item in each iteration
- also you used `const` to decalre your variable but `const` is unchangeable variable it's take just the first value assigned to it there's some cases when you can push items to const but you can't assign then add new items to `const` as text